# Remove type attribute from script and style tags added by WordPress plugins

Tags: php, wordpress

I am using the function below to remove type attribute from a script and style tags but this function doesn't remove the type attribute from the scripts/styles added by the plugins. It only works on my theme files.

```
add_filter('style_loader_tag', 'codeless_remove_type_attr', 10, 2);
add_filter('script_loader_tag', 'codeless_remove_type_attr', 10, 2);

function codeless_remove_type_attr($tag, $handle) {
    return preg_replace( "/type=['\"]text\/(javascript|css)['\"]/", '', $tag );
}
```

Comment: The `script_loader_tag` hook will only work on JS files that have been enqueued properly. If it's not working on your plugins, that means the scripts are not being enqueued properly by the plugin. You would have to modify the plugin files directly.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The following code worked for me, please try this by pasting the code into you function.php file.

```
add_action('wp_loaded', 'prefix_output_buffer_start');
function prefix_output_buffer_start() { 
    ob_start("prefix_output_callback"); 
}

add_action('shutdown', 'prefix_output_buffer_end');
function prefix_output_buffer_end() { 
    ob_end_flush(); 
}

function prefix_output_callback($buffer) {
    return preg_replace( "%[ ]type=[\'\"]text\/(javascript|css)[\'\"]%", '', $buffer );
}
```

Hope this will work for you too.

Comment: After much searching on this topic, this was by far the best answer to the issue encountered. Great work @Tristup

Comment: OMG! I thought there is no solution after trying tons of other codes! but yours is working 100% perfectly as expected :) Thank you

Comment: thanks, finally I got my wordpress theme green in the validator

Comment: @BenjaminSchlegel glad to know that